# How to get D3 Tree link text to transition smoothly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, visualization, data-visualization

**Visualization Goal:** Build a D3 Tree that has text at, both, nodes and links, and that transitions cleanly, when nodes are selected/deselected.

**Problem:** While I can get link text, called "predicates," to show up along the centroid of all link paths, I can't seem to get them to transition in and out "smoothly."

**Question:** Can someone please help me please help me clean up the code and better understand how tree "link" transitions are behaving so I understand the theory behind the code?

**Visualization and Source Location:** http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/

The existing code looks as follows...

```
var linkTextItems = vis.selectAll("g.linkText")
    .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; })

var linkTextEnter = linkTextItems.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "linkText")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.target.y + 20) + "," + (getCenterX(d)) + ")"; });

// Add Predicate text to each link path
linkTextEnter.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", "120")
    .attr("height", "40")
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .html(function(d){ return "<p>" + (linksByIdHash[d.source.id + ":" + d.target.id].predicate) + "</p>"; });

// Transition nodes to their new position.
//var linkTextUpdate = linkTextItems.transition()
    //.duration(duration)
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + ")"; })

//linkTextUpdate.select("linkText")
    //.style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting linkText to the new position of the parents.
var linkTextExit = linkTextItems.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.source.y + 20 + "," + (getCenterX(d)) + ")"; })
  .remove();

linkTextExit.select("linkText")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

function getCenterX(d) {
    var xS = d.source.x;
    var xT = d.target.x;
    if(xS == xT)
      { return (xS - (xS - xT)/2); }
    else if(xS > xT)
      {return (xS - (xS - xT)/2); }
else
  { return (xT - (xT - xS)/2); }
    }
```

**Some Symptoms...**

- When link text transitions in or out, it's choppy / not smooth
- When a branch is collapse, link text doesn't transition to appropriate path centroids

My frustration is that I feel like I'm very close but that I'm missing something very simple/basic.  Any help is greatly appreciate.